# Removing alphabets from string using regexp_replace in Hive

Tags: hive, regexp-replace

Could you confirm if there is a more 'proper' way to remove alphabets from a string like `'2018-10-27T19:57:33Z'`? There are always 2 signs to remove and first needs to be replaced with space, 2nd one at the and of string needs to be replaced with nothing. It's actually nested and if there is a chance to optimize it, It would be great.

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(string, '[[:alpha:]]', ' '),'[[:alpha:]]', '')
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8d713f75bf6575dc85d67832ef6b0e5c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We still needs to use `two regexp_replace` functions because we **are not replacing all alphabets with some replacement value**.

(or)

By using `from_unixtime` and `unix_timestamp` functions we can remove **T,Z** from the string value.

**Ex:**

```
hive> with cte as(select string("2018-10-27T19:57:33Z")ts) 
        select ts,
          regexp_replace(regexp_replace(ts,'T',' '),'Z','') regex_func,
          from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(ts,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") unix_time_func 
        from cte;
+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--+
|          ts           |      regex_func      |    unix_time_func    |
+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--+
| 2018-10-27T19:57:33Z  | 2018-10-27 19:57:33  | 2018-10-27 19:57:33  |
+-----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--+
```

There are other ways using **replace,substring** functions we can achieve the same result.